# Why is my computer constantly resuming from sleep?

Tags: ssd, sleep, power-management, wake-on-lan, acpi

My recently reformatted Windows 8.1 machine keeps resuming from sleep. This is an acute issue ever since I got my SSD (the reason for the reformat), as Hybrid Sleep is out and the system does true sleep and resume very easily. My motherboard is the Intel DP67BGB3.

Here's the outline in an image album:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLPxc.jpg

The text version:

1. System enters sleep.
2. System time synchronizes with hardware clock.
3. Background Intelligent Transfer changes from auto start to demand start.
4. LAN adapter disconnects.
5. Background Intelligent Transfer changes from demand start to auto start.
6. Bluetooth refuses authentication codes.
7. System resumes (reason: "ACPI Sleep Button")
8. LAN adapter reconnects.
9. ???
10. BANKRUPTCY

The LAN adapter, WiFi adapter, and all other adapters in the network category are set not to wake the computer from sleep. Wake Timers are turned off on my power plan. ACPI power button doesn't show up under powercfg's device query, I only get a few keyboard objects. It won't let me change wake_armed devices, even udner Administrator mode.

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting a command prompt by hitting start and then type cmd. Hit Ctrl shift enter to start it as administrator. Then type powercfg /lastwake to get an idea what is causing it to resume from sleep.  Also try powercfg /requests to see what is keeping it awake.

Also try unplugging devices one at a time.

Also see if there is a specific time that it always awakes at.

Comment: If you go to the image album linked, as well as read the last paragraph, you'll see I've already most of this.

Although -requests is showing an HD audio device. Let me look into it.